# input type text value showing undefined in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one input type textbox, passing value from that textbox to the controller in .net mvc via javascript. Now, my problem is that in textbox I put the value but in javascript/jquery alert it showing me undefined.

Here is my code,

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="SVG00001" name="referencecode" id="referencecode" />
<button class="Referencebutton" onclick="AddReferenceCode()"><span>Submit</span></button>
<script>    
    function AddReferenceCode() {        
        alert($('#referencecode').val());
    }
</script>
```

I used javascript as well as jquery type also to get the value from input text. But nothing work.

As per the code seen, I dont think so is there any problem in code still shows the undefined value. Surprised...!!!

Comment: It works for me. Though you have to write actual value in the text box, the placeholder will not be returned by `.val()`

Comment: unclear how that would return undefined

Comment: I removed the placeholder and write the actual code also showing me same output i.e. undefined or null

Comment: @epascarello thats why I am also surprised....!!!

Comment: Are you actually seeing `undefined` or is that what you are saying because the alert is empty?

Comment: @dee-see when I remove  the placeholder and do with javascript it shows me [object HTMLDivElement] in the alert

Comment: @epascarello if you are using jquery it showing empty while with javascript it shows undefined or [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: no clue what "while with javascript" means.... If you do not type anything in it, the value is `""` aka any empty string so it is `alert("");`

Comment: @epascarello if we type anything in the textbox still shows the empty only

Comment: Sounds like jQuery is not finding the element. So what is different in the code above vs what you actually have since the code above works perfectly fine.

Comment: @epascarello hmm can be said. Any idea?

Comment: So what is your actual code that causes the issue since the code above does not.

Comment: Are there any errors when the page loads up?

Comment: which version of jQuery you are using ?